# Regex, how to match: string + any number of characters in between + string

Tags: regex

This seems like a very basic problem, but I just can't find how to do it.

Here is my test string:
E.g.

```
{
    "timezone": "CET",
    "7": [
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"00:00"}, 
        {"opening":"00:00","closing":"02:15"}
    ],
    "1":[
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"16:00"},
        {"opening":"20:00","closing":"00:00"},
        {"opening":"00:00","closing":"03:00"}
    ],
    "2": [
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"16:00"},
        {"opening":"20:00","closing":"00:00"}
    ],
    "3": [
        {"opening":"22:00","closing":"00:00"},
        {"opening":"00:00","closing":"02:15"}
    ],
    "4": [
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"16:00"},
        {"opening":"20:00","closing":"23:15"}
    ],
    "5": [
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"16:00"},
        {"opening":"20:00","closing":"23:15"}
    ],
    "6": [
        {"opening":"13:00","closing":"16:00"},
        {"opening":"20:00","closing":"00:00"}
    ]
}
```

What I have here is a JSON of closing/opening times of a store.

I need to simply check whether the 3rd day of the week has this exact string:`closing":"00:00"},{"opening":"00:00"`

Two things to note here.

- Between the `"3":` and `closing":"00:00"},{"opening":"00:00"` strings ANY number of characters can exist, it is not fixed, since stores can have 1,2 or 3 closing times. If it was fixed I would just use X amount of wildcards in my regex and I would not be asking this question.
- Please also note that the searching of `closing":"00:00"},{"opening":"00:00"` string should not be done outside the bounds of the 3rd day of week. So the closing bracket `]` of the 3rd day of week should be where the matching stops, because I don't want the string to be matched in the remaining days.

Comment: You should definitely parse the JSON instead of using regex

Comment: What language are you using? You can almost certainly just use something like `JSON.parse()`, and should never have to use a regex for JSON.

Comment: The JSON is stored in a Postgre SQL database. I would prefer just to do the matching directly in the DB instead of importing to something like Python. I know postgre has regex functions, not sure about JSON.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports JSON natively. It even has a JSON field type, so you don't have to store it as a string. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse this as JSON and not use a Regex [because JSON is not a](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and using a Regex will only work if your JSON string will *always* have the exact same syntactical and semantic structure, which may or may not be guaranteed in your application.

[Fortunately PostgreSQL has a comprehensive JSON operator and JSON function library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) that you can use even if you're storing JSON as text in your columns (instead of using the JSON column datatypes).

I imagine you'll want something like this (note that I'm not a PostgreSQL expert and this query clause might not work):

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    shops
WHERE
    json_array_length( hours::json->'3' ) == 2
    AND
    hours::json->'3'->0->'closing' = '00:00'
    AND
    hours::json->'3'->1->'opening' = '00:00'
```

Here's how it works:

1. I assume you have a column in your `shops` table named `hours` that has a text type (`varchar`, `nvarchar`, etc), so `hours::json` will parse the column value as JSON blob and instantiate a JSON object that can be queried.
2. First we need to do a safety-check to ensure that there is an entry named `"3"` and it has an array value with exactly 2 elements in it (so we can safely dereference indexes `0` and `1` later on). We do this with `json_array_length( hours::json->'3' ) == 2`.
3. Then we look up the actual inner-values:

   1. `->'3'` will access the object property named `"3"` (as `hours` is an object `{}`, not an array `[]`).
   2. `->0` assumes that the previous `->'3'` returns an array, and then it gets the element at index `[0]` (in this case, `{"opening":"22:00","closing":"00:00"}`).
   3. `->'closing'` then gets the named property 'closing'.
   4. And then we compare it to the expected value of '00:00'.
4. And then repeat the last 3 steps for the element at index `1` and property 'opening'.